# TypeORM save data with relation

Tags: typescript, service, controller, nestjs, typeorm

I am actually saving data with 2 differents succesive create() (then save in my services) with this following code in my controller:

```
const ticket: Partial<Ticket> = {
  ticketId: ticketId,
  dispatch: dispatch,
};

const ticket = await this.ticketsService.create(ticket);

const missions: Partial<Mission>[] = body.items.map((mission) => ({ 
  missionId: mission.missionId, 
  folderId: mission.folderId, 
  ticket: ticket 
}));

await this.missionsService.create(missions);
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
const missions: Partial<Mission>[] = body.items.map((mission) => ({ 
  missionId: mission.missionId, 
  folderId: mission.folderId
}));

const ticket: Partial<Ticket> = {
  ticketId: ticketId,
  dispatch: dispatch,
  mission: missions
};

await this.ticketsService.create(ticket);
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

i think its better you should use subscriber command
it's better for handling RollBack and cleaning code

you can after insert to Mission DB - emit the event for save in the ticketDB

https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/listeners-and-subscribers